# Drupal Partial not being displayed

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have a footer partial

templates/partials/footer.tpl.php

#### Footer..

I have added it to the theme() hook in my template.php file

template.php

```
function scratch_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
    return array(
       'footer' => array('template' => 'templates/partials/footer'),
    );
}
```

However when I am calling it it does not display

page.tpl.php

```
<?php $mainMenu = scratch_get_main_menu(); ?>

<div class="menu">
<ul>
    <?php foreach($mainMenu as $item){
    echo "<li>" . $item['link']['link_title'] . "</li>";
    }?>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have var dumped but to no i just get an empty string

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You've missed this bit from [the docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7):

> Each information array must contain either a 'variables' element or a 'render element' element, but not both

So:

```
function scratch_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
    return array(
       'footer' => array(
         'template' => 'templates/partials/footer',
         'variables' => array(),
       ),
    );
}
```

and a cache clear should fix it